# How to calculate percentage based on age_range in this follwing query

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT c.chronicCondition,count(distinct(p.code)),
   CASE
        WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), p.dob) / 365.25) BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN '30-60'
        WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), p.dob) / 365.25) BETWEEN 60 AND 75 THEN '60-75'
        WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), p.dob) / 365.25) BETWEEN 75 AND 90 THEN '75-90'
        WHEN FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), p.dob) / 365.25) BETWEEN 90 AND 100 THEN '90-100'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS age_range
FROM Patient p
   LEFT JOIN classification c ON p.code = c.patientCode
group by c.chronicCondition
ORDER BY age_range
```

How to  use the column aliases you defined in a query in the same query?

Comment: Do you have an error message? Its not clear what you are asking us

Comment: Use not `FLOOR(DATEDIFF(..` but `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, ..`.

Comment: You must include `age_range` into GROUP BY expression. @RiggsFolly Obvious "not in group by or aggregate".

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting a 1055 error - `Error Code: 1055. Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'p.dob' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. If not, you should read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and enable [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

You should also avoid the overlaps in your age ranges as it makes the intent unclear. The [CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#operator_case) will return the `THEN` expression of the first satisfied condition (`60` evaluates to `30-60`, and not `60-75`).

```sql
SELECT c.chronicCondition, COUNT(DISTINCT p.code) AS num,
    CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60 THEN '30-60'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 61 AND 75 THEN '61-75'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 76 AND 90 THEN '76-90'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN '91-100'
        ELSE 'Other'
    END AS age_range
FROM Patient p
LEFT JOIN classification c ON p.code = c.patientCode
GROUP BY c.chronicCondition, age_range
ORDER BY age_range;
```

To get the percentage for each `age_range` you could use:

```sql
SELECT
    c.chronicCondition,
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60, p.code, NULL)) * 100 / COUNT(DISTINCT p.code)) AS `30-60`,
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 61 AND 75, p.code, NULL)) * 100 / COUNT(DISTINCT p.code)) AS `61-75`,
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 76 AND 90, p.code, NULL)) * 100 / COUNT(DISTINCT p.code)) AS `30-60`,
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 91 AND 100, p.code, NULL)) * 100 / COUNT(DISTINCT p.code)) AS `30-60`,
    ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) NOT BETWEEN 30 AND 100, p.code, NULL)) * 100 / COUNT(DISTINCT p.code)) AS `Other`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.code) AS total
FROM Patient p
LEFT JOIN classification c ON p.code = c.patientCode
GROUP BY c.chronicCondition
ORDER BY c.chronicCondition;
```

It is not clear from your question whether `DISTINCT` is necessary in the `COUNT`s. If `(patientCode, chronicCondition)` is unique, the `DISTINCT` is unnecessary and the query can be simplified a little:

```sql
SELECT
    c.chronicCondition,
    ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 30 AND 60) * 100 / COUNT(p.code)) AS `30-60`,
    ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 61 AND 75) * 100 / COUNT(p.code)) AS `61-75`,
    ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 76 AND 90) * 100 / COUNT(p.code)) AS `30-60`,
    ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) BETWEEN 91 AND 100) * 100 / COUNT(p.code)) AS `30-60`,
    ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.dob, CURDATE()) NOT BETWEEN 30 AND 100) * 100 / COUNT(p.code)) AS `Other`,
    COUNT(p.code) AS total
FROM Patient p
LEFT JOIN classification c ON p.code = c.patientCode
GROUP BY c.chronicCondition
ORDER BY c.chronicCondition;
```

It is also unclear whether the `LEFT JOIN` is intentional. Do you have/want `Patient` rows with no associated `classification` row? If not, this should be changed to `INNER JOIN`, or just `JOIN`.

If this is not what you are looking for, please update your question with sample data and desired output.